# Routing not working in Laravel+React

Tags: laravel, reactjs, url-routing

I need to change the route of my page from `mysite/practice` to `mysite/practice/new`

I have a React project set up in laravel with lumen.

routes.php:

```
$app->get('/practice', ['as' => 'pet_practices', 'middleware' => 'check_vet_roles', 'uses' => 'PetsController@practice']);
```

PetsController.php

```
public function practice(Request $request)
    {
        $variables =$this->getUserInfo($request);
        return view('practice-profile') ->with('variables', $variables);
    }
```

practice-profile.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')


@section('content')
<div id="practice-profile"></div>

@endsection
```

My JSX file

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var PageCollectionComponent  = require('./PageCollectionComponent');

if (document.getElementById('practice-profile')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<PageCollectionComponent  />,document.getElementById('practice-profile'));
}
```

Everything works fine in this setup. When I go to `mysite/practice` page loads fine.

But if I change the route to

```
$app->get('/practice/new', ['as' => 'pet_practices', 'middleware' => 'check_vet_roles', 'uses' => 'PetsController@practice']);
```

and go to `mysite/practice/new` it doesn't work anymore. The layout loads from the blade file, but it doesn't get to the JSX file anymore. Why is that?

In the console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I'm fairly new to this project so it's probably something fundamental that I am missing here.

Comment: The console should show you where is that token exactly in your code, so you can fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the console isn't helpful. There isn't any syntax error in the file because then it shouldn't work with 'mysite/practice' either. I get a "message":"exception 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException' but that just means the route isn't found right? Which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more info. But, maybe the problem occurs because you're moving up a directory level, make sure that your JS file is being loaded from the correct location. If you're using a relative path like `<script src="app.js"></script>` then going a level deeper will try to request `yoursite/practice/app.js` instead of `yoursite/app.js`.